# How to get people search result for out of network connections in linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api, jsapi, linkedin-j, linkedin-jsapi

I am using linkedin JSAPI to find people working in particular company , but my search result is limited to second degree connection is it possible to extend search result to display 3rd and out of network connection.

**NOTE:** In LinkedIn documentation it is described that it is possible to fetch only with first and last name,but in forums it is written as possible with facet search..but how is my question
**Link:**
https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/people-search-api-problem-out-my-network-profiles-search-return-always-empty-result?page=1#comment-34552

This is the code I used

```
IN.API.Raw("/people-search:(num-results,people:(headline,id,positions,first-name,location,public-profile-url))?facet=location,in:7127&facet=past-company,1283&facet=network,O&count=25")
.method("GET").result(function success(result) {
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer

It is impossible to fetch search result for third and outside connection with linkedin basic  plan..need premium account

https://www.linkedin.com/mnyfe/subscriptionv2?displayProducts=&family=general&c=23&trk=vsrp_people_upsell_executiveaccount